# ViewModelScope might get canceled while inserting entries into a Room database

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel, koin

I'm building a score tracking app and I have a screen where you can add new players into a game. It's a simple screen that lets the user specify the player's name and color. This screen has its own `ViewModel`, which I inject into the screen's composable function by using the Koin framework like this:

```kotlin
fun NewPlayerScreen(
    viewModel: NewPlayerScreenViewModel = getViewModel(),
    navController: NavHostController,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
)
```

This ensures that the `ViewModel` lives as long as the screen is visible on the screen. When the user clicks the "save" button on the screen, the new player gets inserted into a Room database. My problem is however, that the insertion into the database is handled by the `NewPlayerScreenViewModel`. As soon as the user submits the new player, the screen exits and the ViewModel gets destroyed, which also means that its `CoroutineScope` gets canceled, which means that my ongoing database operation which is inserting the player into the database might not finish properly.

I know there is one solution; I could hoist the event out of the function like this:

```kotlin
fun NewPlayerScreen(
    viewModel: NewPlayerScreenViewModel = getViewModel(),
    navController: NavHostController,
    onPlayerSave: (newPlayer: Player) -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
)
```

However, this would mean, that I now have to handle the insertion into the database in another `ViewModel`, in my `MainScreenViewModel`, since the parent of my `NewPlayerScreen()` composable is the `MainScreen()`. I don't like this approach, because I'd like my screens to have their own `ViewModel`s handle the database operations for themselves. Are there any other options or is this the proper way to handle this kind of situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could either:

- Wait for the insertion to happen before navigating to the next screen

You can do this by making the insertion function a `suspend` function, creating a `val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()` and then on the save button's onClick callback, do:

```kotlin
coroutineScope.launch {
    viewModel.insertPlayer()
    navigate()
}
```

Doing this, you guarantee that the operations will happend sequentially, with the drawback that the user has to wait until the player is added before navigating to the next screen.

- Schedule the work using [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager)'s `OneTimeWorkRequest`

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. It works, however, isn't it better to handle the Room database operation on the IO thread? Using `Dispatchers.IO`?

Comment: Room actually offloads the work to a different thread if you use `suspend`, so no need to worry about this. Here is the guide: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/async-queries

Comment: In general, you only need to worry about dispatchers when calling blocking functions or functions that are only allowed to be called on the main thread. If you launch in the viewModelScope without changing the dispatcher from Main, that eliminates concerns about calling on main. And suspend functions should never block so you don’t need to worry about them if they come from a library by a competent author, as Room is.

Answer (score 1):

Arguably the best (and officially recommended approach) is to use a long-lived application scope (injected into the `ViewModel`) for operations that should not be cancelled when `ViewModel` is disposed

```
class MyApplication : Application() {  
  // No need to cancel this scope as it'll be torn down with the process
  val applicationScope = CoroutineScope(SupervisorJob() + otherConfig)
}
```

There is a great explanation of why this is the best approach in [this article](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/coroutines-patterns-for-work-that-shouldnt-be-cancelled-e26c40f142ad).